# Material-UI: TablePagination hide next and prev

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How to hide the next and prev button in the `TablePagination` component. Is it something that I have to do in css or configure the component in some way? At the same time I want to keep the exact position of the "Showing ... ".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [no option](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/c3aab53e78396e944a6e36348057a9f0df3ec762/docs/src/pages/components/tables/CustomPaginationActionsTable.js#L62-L75) to hide the next and back `IconButton` in `TablePagination`. So I'm afraid you have to rely on css.

If you want to remove the buttons completely, use `display: none`:

```js
<TablePagination
  {...props}
  nextIconButtonProps={{ style: { display: "none" } }}
  backIconButtonProps={{ style: { display: "none" } }}
/>
```

If you want to hide the buttons and reserve the space where the buttons occupy, use `visbility: hidden`:

```js
<TablePagination
  {...props}
  nextIconButtonProps={{ style: { visibility: "hidden" } }}
  backIconButtonProps={{ style: { visibility: "hidden" } }}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66720179/material-ui-tablepagination-hide-next-and-prev/66724617#66724617]